# from not recognized as an internal or external command beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I think I have successfully installed pip, then installed lxml using `pip install lxml`, then installed requests using `pip install requests`.

I have also downloaded `beautifulsoup4-4.3.2` and extracted it.
I have successfully ran `python setup.py install`
and done `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

I have added `C:\Python\Scripts` in the Environment variables.

However when I write `from bs4 import beautifulsoup4/BeautifulSoup`, I get a syntax error.

It says that `from` is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Also, when I do `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)`, it says that name `BeautifulSoup` is not defined.

Comment: You tried `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: read [Getting started on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#getting-started). Make sure that you can run a simple script such as: `import sys; print(sys.version)`.

Comment: the first error sounds like you are trying to write Python code right in the Windows console (cmd.exe). The second error means that `from bs4 import BeautifoulSoup` before has not been successful (it implies interactive environment unless you explicitly suppressed the import error in your script).

Comment: yes, Gohn67!     Sebastian, thanks for your help. I am not a programmer. Can you please explain in a simpler language where I messed up and what can I do to remedy the situation?

Comment: @g_econ: ["Exercise 0: The Setup" and "Exercise 1: A Good First Program"](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/intro.html) should be enough to get you started.